# Why can we use the arrhenius equation to measure the number of vacancies in a material?

Tags: kinetics, materials, solid-state-chemistry

In a materials science video I was watching today the prof. said we could use the arrhenius equation to estimate the number of vacancy point defects in a material. And gave the following equation:

N<sub>v</sub> = N exp(-Q<sub>v</sub> / K<sub>B</sub>T)

Where N<sub>v</sub> = number of vacancies

N= # of atom sites

Q<sub>v</sub> = energy of vacancy formation

K<sub>B</sub> = Boltzmann constant

T = Temp

I don't understand how we got to that equation from the Arrhenius equation. How do the two relate? How is the above equation derived from the Arrhenius equation?

Comment: I'll try a heuristic undetailed explanation. The formation of vacacies has a cost in enthalpy (because atoms are no longer tightly bonded), although it naturally increases entropy (because there are more possible microstates). It follows that there is a certain Gibbs energy (G = H - TS) that induces an equlibrium, where G is minimized. In chemical equlibrium, G is associated with a given K (equilibrium constant), which is temperature-dependent according the Van't Hoff equation (which can be derived from basic thermodynamics), that is similar to the Arrhenius equation.

Comment: This looks like the Boltzmann equation, perhaps Arrhenius was a slip of the tongue.